# flutter_inappwebview razorpay netbanking issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview, flutter-in-app-purchase, flutter-razorpay

I am using flutter_inappwebview for my website but whenever i go to payment gateway the netbanking page freeze and shows nothing i tried many things nevertheless i couldnt solve the problem.

here is my code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewPage> createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  late InAppWebViewController webViewController;

  final _razorpay = Razorpay();
 

  List<dynamic> paymentData = [];

  fetchData() async {
    const url = "https://api.redesyn.com/orders/place?payment_mode=prepaid";
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    final body = response.body;
    final json = jsonDecode(body);
    setState(() {
      paymentData = json['data'];
    });
    print("11111111111*****************************@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#####%&&&& ");
  }

  InAppWebViewGroupOptions initialOptions = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
        javaScriptEnabled: true,
        verticalScrollBarEnabled: false,
        horizontalScrollBarEnabled: false),
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: true,
    ),
    ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
    ),
  );

  void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {
   
  }

  void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
    
  }

  void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
   
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // fetchData();
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            var isLastPage = await webViewController.canGoBack();
            if (isLastPage) {
              webViewController.goBack();
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              InAppWebView(
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                  url: Uri.parse("https://demo.redesyn.com/"),
                  headers: {
                    'X-Client-Type': 'app',
                  },
                ),
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                  webViewController = controller;
                },
                androidOnPermissionRequest:
                    (controller, origin, resources) async {
                  return PermissionRequestResponse(
                      resources: resources,
                      action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                },
                shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                  var url = navigationAction.request.url!;
                  print("22222222222@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@************ $url");

                  if (url.toString().contains(
                      "https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js")) {
                    print(
                        "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&********************************");
                  }

                  if (![
                    "http",
                    "https",
                    "file",
                    "chrome",
                    "data",
                    "javascript",
                    "about"
                  ].contains(url.scheme)) {
                    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                      await launchUrl(url,
                          mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
                      return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                    }
                  }

                  // https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js

                  // if (url ==
                  //     "https://dev.redesyn.com/orders/place?payment_mode=prepaid") {
                  //   if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                  //     fetchData();
                  //     return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                  //   }
                  // }

                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                },
                initialOptions: initialOptions,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to intercept the the razorpay url and use the native, but it is doing nothing, i have tried many things provided by internet but nothing works.